# On the solvability of a nonlinear differential system

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, differential-galois-theory

A nonlinear formulation of differential Galois theory was discussed [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608492.pdf) and [here for three dimensional nonlinear systems](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5128587) (proof is on pages 6 – 10). For a two dimensional system, the following system of differential equations was considered:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dot{x}_1&=X_1(x_1,x_2),\\
\dot{x}_2&=X_2(x_1,x_2),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
such that $X_1,X_2$ are polynomial functions and $X_1(0,0)\neq0$. Let $K$ denote the differential field of rational functions, with constant field $\mathbb{C}$. The system is Liouvillian integrable iff the differential Galois group of $dx_2/dx_1=X_2(x_1,x_2)/X_1(x_1,x_2)$ over $K$ at $(0,0)$ is solvable. For the four dimensional system
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dot{x}&=X,\\
\dot{X}&=\sigma(Y-X-kx),\\
\dot{Y}&=-Y+rX-XZ,\\
\dot{Z}&=-bZ+XY.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
does an equivalent formulation exist to determine whether Liouvillian integrability (or solvability by quadratures) holds where $k,r,\sigma\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $b=1$? Any help would be much appreciated.

Note that when $k=0$, we have the closed system.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dot{X}&=\sigma(Y-X),\\
\dot{Y}&=-Y+rX-XZ,\\
\dot{Z}&=-bZ+XY.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

As a corollary of Equation 6 and 12 in the second linked paper,
the Lorenz-like system is at least partially integrable when
\begin{equation}
4\sigma r=b^2\frac{(2n+1)^2}{4}-(\sigma-1)^2,
\end{equation}
for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

The following theorem of Ishii may help for a complete integrability criterion.
Assume that the system has a balance $\{{a},{p}\in\mathbb{Q}^4\}$ for which the Kovalevskaya matrix
\begin{equation}
    K=JV_{a}-\mathop{\mathrm{diag}}(p),
\end{equation}
is semi-simple (such that $JV_{a}$ denotes the Jacobian of the system of ODEs at $a$). If the system is completely integrable, then the local general series are Puiseux series.

Comment: Are there any additional information about the constants $k$, $r$, $b$ and $\sigma$?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am particularly interested in the system when $b=1$. Other than that, the constants assume positive real values $k,r,\sigma\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: We need to study the eigenvalues at equilibrium points. This is too difficult with all these undetermined constants.

Comment: When $r>1+k-k/(\sigma+1)$, the system is asymptotically unstable (a real part of $\lambda$ is greater than zero for the linearisation). The only equilibrium occurs at $(0,0,0,0)$ and I am more interested in proving Liouvillian integrability (or if the system is unsolvable).

Comment: As you can see in theorem 5.2 of Goriely's "Integrability and nonintegrability of dynamical systems" (link: https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/3846), the eigenvalues (more specific a resonance condition on them) play a big role in existence of first integrals.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I'll check that out and see if it helps at all (even for specific values of $k,r,\sigma$). Hopefully, a more generalised approach can be used with respect to the constants (i.e. following from what is discussed in https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5128587).